# dismiss view controller UINavigationBar overlaps with status bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I dismiss viewcontroller Navigation bar overlaps with status bar how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

add this code in your first view Controller